# How should I configure multiple Drupal sites to share a CiviCRM database?

Tags: drupal, multisite, civicrm-entity

I have an existing CiviCRM instance on Drupal site (D1). I have a second Drupal site (D2), which does not have CiviCRM. I want to make the CiviCRM instance (data/contacts/settings) from D1 available inside of D2.

I want to have CiviCRM Views integration and CiviCRM Entity module working from both D1 and D2.

Reading the CiviCRM multisite documentation, it is still not clear to me what my ideal setup would be.

I am hoping that someone will share how they think it should be set up!

Comment: This sounds like a fairly standard multi-site use case.  Could you please give some more details about what in the multi-site documentation seems like an unclear choice?

Comment: What are the options you are considering that you are unsure about? The only question I would raise is whether the Drupal users can be shared between sites or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should read about Drupal multi-site feature. That's we can use the same database and same modules if the D2 is working as an parked domain for D1 website.

I would like to share the reference link https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

Please check that one.

Comment: The original poster is precisely not asking about Drupal multisite. The original poster is not asking about sharing a Drupal codebase.